# SSH.net Cisco Router Inital connect failed

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I am hobbyist programmer. I am getting error using Renci.SshNet. It gives me following error at statement `sshclient.Connect();`

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:'The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced'

My code is

```
private void Rstbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    s_ipaddr = IPAddr.Text;

    s_username = UsernameBox.Text;
    s_password = PassBox.Password.ToString();
    SecureString myPass = PassBox.SecurePassword;

    using (var sshclient = new SshClient(s_ipaddr, s_username, s_password)) 
    {
        sshclient.Connect();
    }
}
```

I am using Renci.SshNet.dll directly in the reference no installation from Nuget.

Comment: Is the IP address formatted properly?

Comment: it is in string format

Comment: We can see in the code that it's "string". But we need to see the format of the string. Show us the value of `s_ipaddr`.

Comment: Quick watch shows the value like this     s_ipaddr "10.0.85.250" string

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Can you connect to that IP address with any SSH client from the **same machine** that runs your C# code?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Yes, I can connect through Putty from the same system on SSH.

Comment: @ikkentim I don't know about stacktrace.

Comment: I used my same project file on different PC and it worked.